# Hide BottomNavigationView on Navigation in Xamarin.Forms (Android Only)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, tabbar, bottomnavigationview

I am using the new Xamarin.Forms feature to set the Tabbar at Bottom for Android using below properties

xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"

I need to hide the tabbar when navigated to other pages. I had written a custom renderer inherited from TabbedPageRenderer but i am not able to get the instance of BottomNavigationView using OnElementChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst it is possible, according to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80033/how-can-i-correctly-use-a-tabbedpage-inside-a-navigationpage) setting a Tabbed Page inside a Navigation Page is not recommended by Apple.

A better solution would be to open a modal page over the TabbedPage. I suppose the modal page can be a NavigationPage, but I have not tried this.

Comment: I used this approach and works fine just the model transition looks a bit Offbeat unlike navigation transition.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should keep TabbedPage inside NavigationPage and push new pages on top of TabbedPage.

You cannot get BottomNavigationView reference since it is a [private field](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs#L37). Although, you can use reflection to set its values, which I strongly advice against.

```
var info = typeof(TabbedPageRenderer).GetTypeInfo();
var _bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)info.GetField("_bottomNavigationView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this);`
```

Comment: The code works but it does not adjust the bottom space. The patch area of tabbar remains. Tried the navigation approach but still the tabbar is visible in this case.

Comment: Keeping TabbedPage inside NavigationPage definitely works, please post the code for better understanding. Also, I totally agree with @Tom, it is bad design to keep TabbedPage inside NavigationPage, only use it if there is no other way